# What led Mike Lindell to specify Aug 13 for a claimed Trump reinstatement?

Tags: united-states, president, donald-trump

It is being widely reported that My Pillow CEO Mike Lindell has [claimed that Trump would be reinstated on August 13](https://www.reuters.com/article/factcheck-trump-reinstated-idUSL1N2OV1W3). It is clear that there is no process by which this could occur, so we already know the claim is false.

What I am curious about is the specificity of the claim - what justification has Lindell given for the specific date of August 13th? Has some interpretation or misinterpretation lead to the attachment of that specific date to the reinstatement claim?

Comment: I always wonder why people mentions the fact that Mike Lindell is CEO of a pillow manufacturer, as if that gave him special knowledge or any kind of relevance when making bold claims about US politics.

Comment: @SJuan76 He's not *just* "the CEO of a pillow manufacturer". He's the CEO of a pillow manufacturer that has used promotional codes like "FightforTrump,"  "Proof" and "QAnon" in its sales campaigns.

Comment: @SJuan76 Disambiguation... the person "best known for".

Comment: Kinda surprised to see this question on politics, seems like it would be a better fit for skeptics

Comment: @GammaGames the OP initially posted the question on Skeptics but it was closed. I edited out that meta-commentary from the question though :P I don't think the question is particularly out of place here?

Comment: @CDJB I'm used to seeing conspiracy theory questions over there, but I do see how the question is narrow enough to be be a good question here. I also didn't check the revision history, that would've told me about the previous question!

Comment: A national sense of paraskevidekatriaphobia?

Comment: @SJuan76: Most of the references I've seen have been in the opposite sense, basically asking why this pillow maker should have any particular insight into US politics.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This claim doesn't appear to have come about as some sort of misinterpretation of a constitutional process or other legislative pathway, but as a predicted response to the publication of information he claims to possess which will supposedly make President Biden & Vice President Harris' positions untenable.

Lindell first made his August 13th prediction on July 4th - at the same time he confirmed the dates he plans to host a "cyber symposium". During the event, held between August 10th and August 12th, he claims that he will reveal "the cyber data and the packet captures" - supposed proof that President Trump was the true winner of the November 2020 election. There appears to be no other attempted justification for the proposed date of August 13th except for it being the day after the conclusion of this event.

Of course, even if Biden and Harris were to resign, the presidential line of succession would mean that the Speaker of the House of Representatives would become president, not Donald Trump.

Speaking on [Real America's Voice](https://twitter.com/patriottakes/status/1419680011166965770), Lindell said:

> Once we have the symposium, by the night of the 12th or the morning of
> the 13th, if everyone has seen it including the administration that's
> in there now that didn't win, maybe, you know, Biden and Harris would
> say 'Hey, we're here to protect the country' and resign. And, you
> know, I'm serious!

[The Sun](https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/15701638/mike-lindell-biden-harris-will-resign-democrats-regret-voting/) also reported on his claims:

> Lindell's speculation comes as he vows to showcase proof the evidence
> was stolen during his "cyber symposium" event, which is conveniently
> scheduled for August 10 through 12.
>
> "It gives me hope that even your Democrats," he said. "They're seeing
> now firsthand what government can do and how bad socialism and
> communism can be."
>
> "When we get through this and the Supreme Court pulls down this
> election -- like I've been telling everybody -- when they do this,
> it's going to be a great uniting and that gives me hope."

Comment: Does the Supreme Court have the legal authority to "pull down" (i.e., invalidate) an election? If so, who in that case would become (possibly acting) president? The regular constitutional line of succession assumes that the successors were legitimately elected or determined, so it may not apply. It would not *prima facie* seem unreasonable to argue that the previous president was never properly replaced, so he stays in office, in an acting position, until proper elections have been held and the new president assumes office.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica : this would be an interesting separate question on its own.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: see [this 1995 legal review](https://digitalcommons.law.villanova.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2930&context=vlr). The upshot seems to be that the courts have an assortment of remedies for election fraud (up to and including reversing an election), but that (a) the evidentiary bar is exceedingly high, and (b) the federal system can only become involved on appeal from state supreme courts. Lindell's story-line is a bit of a crack-fantasy; it just does't work that way.

Comment: @TedWrigley Interesting read. But from what I understand there, the Abstentation Doctrine is not absolute -- if a federal statute is violated, "the plaintiffs need not have a state forum hear these federal
claims. A party may simultaneously pursue these claims in the state
and federal court systems" (p. 881) Crack fantasy notwithstanding, of course ;-).

Comment: My first thought when reading, "as a predicted response to the publication of information he claims to possess which will supposedly make President Biden & Vice President Harris' positions untenable" was about March 4th and how Hillary was supposed to be arrested.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: I'm not enough of a legal scholar to opine on that, really. But I suspect the Courts would hold that this is the purpose of the certification process, and that after an election has been certified, it falls on legislative bodies to impeach and remove officials. Lindell would not only have to convince the court that his evidence is overwhelming; he'd have to explain why a broad bipartisan  range of elected and appointed officials saw fit to certify the election in the first place.

Comment: Standard IMO advisory : The UK's Sun newspaper is a tabloid and is *not* generally considered an unbiased or reliable source for information.  I know you're only quoting what they say Lindell said, but I would generally double check quotes the Sun reports.  YMMV.

Comment: @StephenG I totally agree; finding a more reputable source that actually bothered to report on Lindell’s comments proved to be a bit of a challenge for some reason though :P

Comment: @TedWrigley Interesting read, but holy footnotes batman!

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica - Even assuming that the election was ruled invalid, the previous president would still be out of office, since their term reached its Constitutionally-specified ending.  There's several questions on here addressing it, but we'd end up with Acting President Pelosi until such time as "a President or Vice President shall have qualified".

Comment: @Bobson Well, after reading that paper I am under the impression that the courts can basically implement any remedy which in their judgement reflects the outcome of the vote if the fraud had not taken place, if that is possible to determine -- including declaring the nominal loser the actual winner (in [Marks vs. Stinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_G._Stinson) which is discussed in the paper that happened actually *twice!*). That's what Lindell must have in mind, if anything.

Comment: I'm a little interested to know if there is some sort of equivalent of a double jeopardy rule for this sort of thing or are people going to be able to constantly raise the specter of revelations that will put Trump back in office.

Comment: @EricNolan There is not even a *single* jeopardy rule for this. Overturning a presidential election in the United States is already unprecedented. Even if there would suddenly show up irrefutable evidence of wide-spread election fraud (all attempts to find any were unsuccessful so far), the courts would not really know what to do with that. The electoral college has voted and the congress has ratified the results. Annulling the election now would be constitutional no-mans land.

Comment: Also remember that George W. Bush also remained president, even after it was discovered that he only won the critical votes in Florida because a lot of people who actually wanted to vote for Al Gore accidentally voted for 3rd party candidate Pat Buchanan because of a misleading ballot design. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_United_States_presidential_election_recount_in_Florida. And that's far more pressing evidence for an election error in a far more narrow election than anything Trump and his fans were able to dig up so far.